# Formation of MVT on the basis of GeometryCollection

Tags: postgis, mapbox-vector-tile

The PostGIS documentation for the ST_AsMVT method states that [ST_AsMVTGeom](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html) can accept a GeometryCollection for the initial formation of an MVT object. I execute ST_AsMVTGeom with ST_Collect combining LineString and MultiPoints. However, already at this stage I get a MultiLineString that outputs only a line with no points. When executing ST_AsMVTGeom with only points or line passed to ST_Collect, the result corresponds to the object given (given a line - I get a line, given points - I get points).
Is it possible to get MVT object with GeometryCollection passed to it using ST_AsMVTGeom? Is it possible to package multiple feature sets into an MVT using ST_AsMVT?

Example of a request code

```
select
         ST_AsMVT(q)
    FROM (
        select
            ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(
                ST_AsMVTGeom(
                    st_transform(ST_Collect(lg.line, replace(ST_AsEWKT(lg.line), 'LINESTRING', 'MULTIPOINT')::geometry), 3857),
                    ST_TileEnvelope({z}, {x}, {y}),
                    4096,
                    0,
                    true
                ), 10
            ) AS point_geom
        FROM
            "LineGeometry" lg
    ) q
```

Comment: There is not ST_Collection function. Please show an actual example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is necessary to pass merged queries, in this case MVT will contain features for both geometries.

```
select
     ST_AsMVT(q)
FROM (
    select
        ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(
            ST_AsMVTGeom(
                st_transform(replace(ST_AsEWKT(lg.line), 'LINESTRING', 'MULTIPOINT')::geometry, 3857),
                ST_TileEnvelope({z}, {x}, {y}),
                4096,
                0,
                true
            ), 10
        ) AS point_geom
    FROM
        "LineGeometry" lg
    union
    select
        ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(
            ST_AsMVTGeom(
                st_transform(lg.line, 3857),
                ST_TileEnvelope({z}, {x}, {y}),
                4096,
                0,
                true
            ), 10
        ) AS point_geom
    FROM
        "LineGeometry" lg
) q
```